# Variable number of inputs and outputs in Python Block?

Tags: python, block

I am building a GNURadio block in Python that has a variable number of input, So I can change the number of input in each simulation.
I use  self.k=k to get the number of input as:

```
def __init__(self, k=4):  # only default arguments here
    """arguments to this function show up as parameters in GRC"""
    self.k=k  ....
    in_sig=[np.float32 for k in range(k)],
```

However, this works only when I change the value of k inside the python code

```
def __init__(self, k=3):
```

or

```
def __init__(self, k=2 ) ....
```

How do I make it change automatically from the block embedded itself without change the codes?

Comment: That's just the default. You can specify a different value when you create a class instance. `x = ClassName(k=3)`

Answer (score 1):

"""
Embedded Python Blocks:

Each time this file is saved, GRC will instantiate the first class it finds
to get ports and parameters of your block. The arguments to **init**  will
be the parameters. All of them are required to have default values!

```py
import numpy as np
from gnuradio import gr


class blk(gr.sync_block):  # other base classes are basic_block, decim_block, interp_block
    """Embedded Python Block example - a simple multiply const"""

    def __init__(self, example_param=1, Nr=4, Nt=4):  # only default arguments here
        """arguments to this function show up as parameters in GRC"""
        self.Nr = Nr
        self.Nt = Nt
        gr.sync_block.__init__(
            self,
            name='Embedded Python Block',   # will show up in GRC
            in_sig=[np.float32 for k in range(Nr)],
            out_sig=[np.float32 for k in range(Nt)],
        )
        # if an attribute with the same name as a parameter is found,
        # a callback is registered (properties work, too).
        self.example_param = example_param

    def work(self, input_items, output_items):
        """example: multiply with constant"""
        output_items[0][:] = input_items[0] * self.example_param
        output_items[1][:] = input_items[1] * self.example_param
        return len(output_items[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you gave the parameter k a default value in case it wasn't set. If you want the variable to be something else than the default value you will have to set it when calling the method.

```
class Radio():

    def __init__(self, k=4):  # only default arguments here
        self.k=k
        print("k equals: " + self.k)


Radio(k=6)   #prints "k equals: 6"
Radio()      #prints "k equals: 4"
```

Comment: should I add this class before:    class blk(gr.sync_block):  or replace it?

Comment: I was just assuming that you have a class since you wrote a __init__() method. If you just named your method that way then simply calling the method will be enough. You would have to write something like `__init__(k=10)`

Comment: The problem is that it is taking the default value which I write in code, not the new value I input it. For example, if I write  def __init__(self, k=4) >> it takes k=4,  and if I change value K inside the codes it works, however, when I change it in Gnuradio block it still takes the default values

Comment: Can you please upload all of your code so that I can get a better understanding of your problem?

Comment: I have already posted it, Could you please check it?